# Excel custom time fomat elapsed time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to format some elapsed time in an Excel cell. The cell should show hours and minutes. This is possible using the format `[h]:mm`.
Using a thousand-seperator is not possible with this format.
Finally, the output should automatically append `:00`, if the user does not enter this minutes.
I tried some formats, but none give me the desired results:

```
  input  | desired    |  output with a custom cell format |
   value |  output    |      [h]:mm    |       #.###":00" | 
-----------------------------------------------------------
   12:34 |      12:34 |       12:34    |            1:00  | 
  123:45 |     123:45 |      123:45    |            5:00  |
 1234:56 |   1.234:56 |     1234:56    |           51:00  | 
12345:56 |  12.345:56 |    12345:56    |        12345:56  |
   12    |      12:00 |      288:00    |           12:00  |
  123    |     123:00 |     2952:00    |          123:00  |
 1234    |   1.234:00 |    29616:00    |        1.234:00  |
12345    |  12.345:00 |   296280:00    |       12.345:00  |
```

Edit: the original table was misleading. Reformated to better show the issue.

No calculation needs to be done.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you simplify that `12345:56` is what `12345` Hrs & `56` Secs and the expected reult `12.345:56` is should read as what `12` Hrs,, `345` Mints,, & `56` Secs or what?

Comment: Thank you. For clarification: I'm looking for hours and minutes only. It should read: twelvethousendthreehundertfourtyfive hours and fiftysix minutes.
The last line should read twelvethousendthreehundertfourtyfive hours and zero minutes.

Comment: What is input cells format? real datatype, real value...

Comment: Why aren't all the input values in hours? 12, 123, 1234 etc should be 12:00, 123:00 and 1234:00 etc, otherwise excel will assume they are *days*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is `12345:56` that's going to be a text value per definition (it's simply not a valid numeric value) and you will need some sort of translation/calculation to build a custom format on.

```
=IF(colon in string is true, the format left substring as ..... etc. etc.
```

The only way I can see this working

---

**Option 1**

- With the way you input data (including the colon),
- To format the input cells,
- With no further calculation needed,

as per your request, is to go on to your settings:

- File > Options > Advanced > Change decimal seperator to `:`
- Format your range to numbers with two decimals and click the 'use thousands seperator` button

Now any number you type will both use the `.` as thousands seperator and the `:` before the decimals without any calculations (as per your question)

[image]

I also assumed your desired output for your second to last value should have the thousands seperator?

---

**Option 2**

Another option would be to use another adjacent cell to output your expected result. This way you can leave the decimal seperator as is but:

- Format the input column as text
- Input the following formula in the adjacent column (see example, assuming your decimal seperator would be the comma):

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,":",","),"#.###,00"),",",":")
  ```

[image]

Comment: @Smock, offcourse, I agree. It's just that OP want's to enter values like `12345:56` that would format like a number. Since that value per definition must be text (it's not a valid numeric value), I don't see any other way than to change the decimal delimiter. The other option is to output a translated value through functions in another adherent cell.

Comment: Sorry - didn't spot the no calculation in the OP - voted up for option 2 especially, nice and simple!

Comment: @Smock no worries. It's not sure for me either if OP meant no further calculations after input or with input OR no further calculations needed with the actual output. I have put another option in just to be sure (just seen yours too)

Comment: same result but yours is so much more elegant !

Comment: Thank you very much. I chose option 2 which is quite elegant.